# Resolving read timeout error while using nba_api

Tags: python, timeout, nba-api

I am trying to get career stats and awards from `nba_api`, but I'm getting a read timeout error.

I'm using the following as a baseline for a project.

```
from nba_api.stats.static import players 
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import playercareerstats
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import PlayerAwards
all_players = players.get_players()

for i in all_players:
        Player_id = i["id"]
        Player_careerstats = playercareerstats.PlayerCareerStats(Player_id).career_totals_regular_season.get_data_frame()
        awards = PlayerAwards(Player_id).get_data_frames()
```

However, I receive this error:

```
ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stats.nba.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)
```

I don't know if I am asking the `nba_api` for too much information since it's every player, or maybe if it's taking too long to process. If instead of trying to collect the data for every nba player I ask a user to input a name, I am able to collect and store data for each player they input. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will receive this due to too many requests in a certain time frame. Usually you just have to wait a couple of minutes but could be up to about an hour or so. Also, your request for all players is definitely a lot of code, because it is requesting every player in NBA history... it would probably work better if you specified the season.. not really sure what your end goal is though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35588117)